# .Net Core 2.0 Configuring Appsettings for multiple environments

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

I have multiple appsettings files such as appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json and appsettings.Production.json in my solution. The appsettings.json file is designed to run locally while the rest have configurations required to run in different environments that run on different servers. Currently, our build is run in such a way that the environment is given as a parameter when run, which allows it to choose the correct appsettings file. We now want to check if we can just transform the files such that the appsettings.json file gets the altered values in the others. I know that setting up environment variables is an option but I wanted to check whether there is another method.